# State inside mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

i have :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    slipsRadioClickHandler: (value) => {
      dispatch(slipsRadioClicked(value));
      switch (value) {
        case 'slips': {
          dispatch(requestSlips());
          dispatch(setExpandCollapse('slipsHide', true, 0))
          break;
        }
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

But the setExpandCollapse('slipsHide', true, 0) must be dispatched 17 times which is the length of a List. This list is in the state. How can i access this list to dispatch my action list. length times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` is not a place where you should be having your code logic. Its intended to bind action to props for the component

Change it with

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    slipsRadioClickHandler: (value) => {
         dispatch(slipsRadioClicked(value));
      },
    requestSlips: dispatch(requestSlips()),
    setExpandCollapse: () => {dispatch(setExpandCollapse('slipsHide', true, 0))}

  }
);
```

and in the component you need to loop over the list made available to it by the `mapStateToProps`

```
var value = 'slips'    // set the value how you want to 

this.props.List.map(function(item){
     switch (value) {
        case 'slips': {
          this.props.requestSlips();
          this.props.setExpandCollapse();
          break;
        }
        default:
          break;
      }
})
```